# How to mapping a JPA entity to MsSQL View using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, view

I have existing `view("user_authenticate")` in my database. I want to mapping existing view with **JPA Entity**. Below code is not working, it always gone to create a new table in my database but it's not using my existing view.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_authenticate")
@Immutable
public class UserAuthLogin {

@Id
private int UserId;
private String userName;
private String userPassword;
private Date personnelNo;
private Date reportingToId;
private String email;
```

Why is this happening?
What i need to change for that?

Comment: If you are using hibernate you could try to add hibernate-specific @Subselect

Comment: Just to make sure. Your view name is user_authenticate and the user you are connecting is able to access the view?

Comment: I'm using spring boot JPA. my view name is same user_authenticate, user are able to connect but every time going to create new table instead of using existing view,  getting error " com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'user_authenticate' in the database."